# Nested Links & Buttons In A Card With Link NextJs

Tags: css, typescript, next.js, hyperlink, card

I 've searched a lot on S.O. but I could not find any answer that works 100%.
My problem is that I have a card component in a NextJs application that is wrapped around a `<Link>`
tag. I also have one more `<Link>` tag inside, 2 external links (`<a>` tags) and a button. But none of these work. I have tried putting `position: relative` to the buttons and anchor tags but it partialy solved the problem (I can navigate to the link **ONLY** if I use the middle click of my mouse, which opens the link to a new tab). I want to make it work such that any clicks will be registered.

---

**Card Component**

```
<Link href={`/${song.singer}/${song.title}`} passHref>
        <div className={style.cardOutter}>
            <div className={style.cardHeader} style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${sdDefault(song.thumbnail)})` }}></div>
            <div className={style.cardBody}>
                <p>{song.title}</p>
                {song.fts !== '' ? 
                    <div className={style.card_fts}>
                        <span>{song.fts}</span>    
                    </div>
                :
                    null
                }
                <div className={style.cardInfoCont}>
                    <small>[{song.lang}] {song.album} - {song.genre}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className={style.cardButtons}>
                <a href={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${song.thumbnail}`} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer' title='Listen On YouTube'><YouTubSimpleIcon color='#ff0000' width={30} height={30} /></a>
                <button disabled={!authContext.isAuth} title='Add To Favouarites'><HeartIcon color='#ff0000' width={30} height={30} /></button>
                <a href={`https://open.spotify.com/${song.spotifyURL === undefined ? '' : song.spotifyURL}`} target='_blank' rel='noreferrer' title='Listen On Spotify'><SpotifySimpleIcon color='#1db954' width={30} height={30} /></a>
            </div>
            <div className={style.cardLyricsBtn}>
                <Link href={`/${song.singer}`} passHref>
                    <button>   
                        Check The Artist!
                    </button>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Link>
```

**SCSS File**

```
.cardOutter {
width: 250px;
height: fit-content;
border-radius: 5px;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 2rem;
background-color: $primaryBlack;
color: $lightWhite;
transition: transform 250ms linear;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
cursor: pointer;
.cardHeader {
    @include mixins.d-flex(center, center, row);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.cardBody {
    width: 100%;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
    p {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    .card_fts {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .cardInfoCont {
        @include mixins.d-flex(center, center, row);
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: .4rem;
    }
}
.cardButtons {
    @include mixins.d-flex(center, space-around, row);
    margin: .5rem 0;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    button {
        @include mixins.naturalButton();
        @include mixins.d-flex(center, center, row);
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
    }
    a {
        @include mixins.simpleAnchor();
        @include mixins.d-flex(center, center, row);
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 100;
    }
}
.cardLyricsBtn {
    @include mixins.d-flex(center, center, row);
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    button {
        @include mixins.naturalButton();
        @include mixins.d-flex(center, center, row);
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        width: 100%;
        padding: .5rem 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
        transition: background 200ms linear;
    }
    a {
        @include mixins.simpleAnchor();
        @include mixins.d-flex(center, center, row);
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        font-weight: 500;
        width: 100%;
        padding: .5rem 0;
        border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is not really related to Next.js. You'd have the same issues with normal anchor tags because nesting links produces invalid HTML, though there are some workarounds [like putting the nested link into an `object` tag](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/nested-links/).

Other than that, you could try the following approaches:

1. Handle either the container link or the nested links via an `onClick` handler instead of an anchor tag.
2. Don't nest your links in the HTML tree but instead make them siblings and align them using only CSS. You could use a `div` container and position all of your links with `position: absolute` inside that div.

In any case you will probably also need to look at event bubbling and add an `onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}` where necessary.